# MessageBox Top Most True

Tags: c#, vb.net, messagebox, msgbox, topmost

is there way to make the default messagebox ( `MessageBox.Show()` ) TopMost true which also stays on top even if the messagebox lost the focus?
I don't want to create a custom one.
Is there a way doing it by using SetWindowHook or something similar?
I already researched a lot but all solutions I found were not working.
Can someone help me out how to do this in VB.net or C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to p/invoke the [`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505.aspx) function and pass the `MB_SYSTEMMODAL` flag.

Comment: Thats sounds interessting. I will have a look at this now. :^)

Comment: There is MB_TOPMOST constant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @prq I've heard reports that `MB_TOPMOST` is ignored on some modern Windows versions. Anyway `MB_SYSTEMMODAL` certainly works.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.
This will show a messagebox on top of all windows opened, doesn't matter if they have Topmost options or not, the messagebox appears always in front.

```
    Public Enum MessageBoxResult As UInteger
        Ok = 1
        Cancel
        Abort
        Retry
        Ignore
        Yes
        No
        Close
        Help
        TryAgain
        ContinueOn
        Timeout = 32000
    End Enum

    Public Enum MessageBoxOptions As UInteger
        SystemModal = &H1000
        NoFocus = &H8000
        SetForeground = &H10000
        Topmost = &H40000
    End Enum

    <DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="MessageBoxW", SetLastError:=True, Charset:=CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Public Shared Function MessageBox(hwnd As IntPtr, _
      <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> lpText As String, _
      <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)> lpCaption As String, _
      <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> uType As MessageBoxOptions) As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)> MessageBoxResult
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MessageBox(IntPtr.Zero, TextBox2.Text, TextBox1.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK Or MessageBoxOptions.SystemModal + MessageBoxOptions.Topmost + MessageBoxOptions.SetForeground + MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is what I told you right? Also, don't be so sure that another topmost window cannot appear on top of yours.

Comment: Well I opened the messagebox with a button click from my form. For testing I've Set the the form to topmost aswell. When i open the messagebox it appears in front of the topmostform.  As soon as I click on the form again the form gets in forground and the msgbox gets in the background. Its not always on top, only on its execution.

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can fix that up?:)

Comment: Yes, I do know why that occurs. However, you seem to want to answer the question yourself. I'm not really encouraged to do more in the circumstances. I'd prefer us to deal with the original question before moving on to this new question.

Comment: I dont think it is necessary to create a new question for this so I modified it ;) I am really interessted why that is. Do you mind telling me?:)

Comment: Yes I do mind actually. I think I answered the question. I don't understand why you repeated my answer here. I do understand why your topmost window is not staying on top. But I don't think that was the original question.